# Angular 10: disable perfect-scrollbar if not have more item to scrolling

Tags: css, angular, perfect-scrollbar

I used perfect-scrollbar for scrolling, but when I have less items for example 2 items that don't require scrolling that stay displayed. I'm looking for a solution to hide this scroll if I don't need to scroll and more than that I don't have the elements to scroll.

please help.

```
        <perfect-scrollbar [config]="configScroll">
          <ul ">
            <li *ngFor="let sub of subMenuItem.submenu; let i = index">
                        <ng-template >
                          <a>
                            <div>test</div>
                          </a>
                        </ng-template>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </perfect-scrollbar>
```

Comment: use `overflow: auto`, instead `overflow: scroll` 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Comment: @izmaylovdev Thank you very much for your answer, I added this code:<perfect-scrollbar [config]="configScroll" style="overflow: auto;">   but nothing has changed

Comment: could you please add link to exact library you using?

Comment: @izmaylovdev i use "ngx-perfect-scrollbar"

Comment: Does `scrollIndicators` is set to `true` in your config?

Comment: @izmaylovdev i have default config and i have this :
    handlers,
    wheelSpeed,
    swipeEasing,
    suppressScrollX,
    suppressScrollY,
    wheelPropagation,
    useBothWheelAxes,
    scrollingThreshold,
    minScrollbarLength,
    maxScrollbarLength,
    scrollXMarginOffset,
    scrollYMarginOffset.

Comment: @izmaylovdev yes <perfect-scrollbar [config]="configScroll" [scrollIndicators]="true">